# Recursive encoder, binary delay operator, convolutional codes

Tags: coding-theory

Say we have a recursive encoder and we can write the codewords $x^j$ in terms of input bits $u^i$ and binary delay operators as

$x^1 = \frac{D}{1-D^3}u^1 + \frac{D^2}{1-D^3}u^2$.

Maybe this is really obvious, but I'm confused about this delay operator which we haven't justified in any real sense. How does a delay in the denominator act on the input bit? I don't understand how we can even define it meaningfully - what if $D^3 = 1$ etc?

Comment: In convolutional encoding denominators are realized by having a feedback loop in the encoder circuitry. You need to remember that the input streams $u^1,u^2$ really are formal power series like $u^1(D)=\sum_{i\ge0} u^1(i)D^i$. And in the ring of formal power series polynomials with non-zero constant term have an inverse. By the geometric sum formula
$$\frac1{1-D}=1+D+D^2+D^3+\cdots$$ and similarly
$$\frac1{1-D^3}=\sum_{k=0}^\infty D^{3k}.$$ Using denominators in convolutional coding is necessary, if you want encoding to be systematic.

Comment: A downside of denominators is that those power series have infinitely many non-zero terms. This means that not all finite input sequences will terminate the encoder properly. There are various ways of handling this issue. Unfortunately I am not very well informed about the pros and cons of various solutions.

Comment: And... $D^3=1$ is meaningless as a possibility. How could "delaying a stream by three clock ticks" be the same as "not doing anything"?